# jQuery - onclick event does not change class after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*Functionality:*

When I click on element with class `thumb_like` or `thumb_unlike` then I will add/remove like for image with POST. Element with class `thumb_count` will increase/decrease by action of user. If he like add 1 to current count etc...

*thumb_unlike is default status where user did not liked image*

**Problem:**

When I click on element with class `thumb_like`/`thumb_unlike` it will do as told, but second click do not change class and user can add/remove more than just 1 like (*increase thumb_count by 1*)

HTML markup:

```
<div class="image_box">
    <div class="image">...</div>
    <div class="image_info">
        <div class="thumb_like" data-id="1"></div>
        <div class="thumb_count">10</div> likes | 0 comments
    </div>
</div>

<div class="image_box">
    <div class="image">...</div>
    <div class="image_info">
        <div class="thumb_unlike" data-id="2"></div>
        <div class="thumb_count">55</div> likes | 0 comments
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".thumb_unlike").click(function () {
        var image_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var count = $(this).next(".thumb_count").text();
        $(this).next(".thumb_count").html(parseInt(count) + 1)
        $.post('..url..' + image_id);

        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass('thumb_like');
    });

    $(".thumb_like").click(function () {
        var image_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var count = $(this).next(".thumb_count").text();
        $(this).next(".thumb_count").html(parseInt(count) - 1)
        $.post('..url..' + image_id);

        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass('thumb_unlike');
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about `.toggle()`?

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak  You mean `thumb_like/thumb_unlike` or `thumb-like/thumb-unlike `?

Comment: @FaresM. sorry, misspell in code, I was writing simple example to demonstrate problem. It is fixed now. It is `thumb_like` / `thumb_unlike`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listeners get attached to elements when the function gets called. The way you have it, listeners are attached to the thumbs themselves. I think the easiest way around this would be to attach the listener to a parent element and delegate to the thumbs. Like so:

```
$('.parent_div').on('click', '.thumb_like', function() {
  //thumb_like code here
});

$('.parent_div').on('click', '.thumb_unlike', function() {
  //thumb_like code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to have the ability to toggle - I'd recommend one function. You can do this without even adjusting your HTML like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.thumb_like, .thumb_unlike', function() {
        var image_id = $(this).attr('data-id'),
            isLike = $(this).hasClass('thumb_like');
        $(this).toggleClass('thumb_like thumb_unlike')
               .next('.thumb_count')
               .text(function(_, i) { return +i + (isLike ? 1 : -1); });
        $.post('..url..', { 
            id: image_id,
            action: isLike ? 'like' : 'unlike'
        });
    });
});
```

This binds one function up at a higher div [as evan suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28649739/13249), but also allows for much less code, fewer event handlers, and is (IMO) easier to maintain since you're dealing with the logic once. You can additionally use a single server-side route for like & unlike.

[You can play with it in a jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/H56Mp/5/).